# Understanding Java character encodings

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, nio

Please help me understand the output of the following lines of code:

```
byte[] byteArray1 = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode("hello wor").array();
System.out.println(byteArray1.length); // 9 - This is as expected.

byte[] byteArray2 = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode("hello world").array();
System.out.println(byteArray2.length); // 12 - Shouldn't it be 11?

byte[] byteArray3 = Charset.forName("UTF-16").encode("hello wor").array();
System.out.println(byteArray3.length); // 37 - Why?

byte[] byteArray4 = Charset.forName("UTF-16").encode("hello world").array();
System.out.println(byteArray4.length); // 45 - Why?
```

Comment: Weird ! I'm eager to see someone answer to it.

Comment: Not weird at all. You're looking at the size of the byte array underlying a `ByteBuffer`. All you can say is that will be at least as big as the number of bytes needed to encode the data. This is like looking at the *capacity* of an `ArrayList` after you've added 5 items, and being surprised if it's not 5.

Comment: And in future, if there's an aspect of an answer you don't understand, it would be better to request more clarification in comments rather than asking what is effectively a duplicate question.

Comment: Of course it is not weird for someone who knows... Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Jon - Was not really sure whether to continue asking for clarifications there yesterday or to ask a new question. I still didn't get an answer to my question though. :)

Comment: You haven't asked for clarification at all in this question - I've explained that you're looking at the size of the underlying byte array in the ByteBuffer. Why would you assume that that is going to be *exactly* the same size as the final encoded text? If you're going to ask for more information, you need to give more details in the question or comment, not just repeat what's already been asked.

Comment: `size of the underlying byte array in the ByteBuffer` - Ok. So, why is it that when I am encoding `hello world` and `abcd efgh` using UTF-16 for example, the length is 45 in the first case and 37 in the second? Also, when I am encoding upto 9 characters using UTF-8(`lkjiefghi` or `abcdefghi`), the length is as expected but the moment when I am encoding more than 9 characters, the result is not as expected(different results for UTF-8 and UTF-16).